# Use of uninitialized value changes under Windows and linux

Tags: perl

I'm developing a small Perl script to automate some server tasks and when I test it on my Windows machine everything works, but when I upload it to my Linux server the script returns multiple:

```
Use of uninitialized value $line in chomp at CreateEntity.pl line 52, <HANDLE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $line in string ne at CreateEntity.pl line 52, <HANDLE> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value $string in substitution (s///) at CreateEntity.pl line 67, <HANDLE>
Use of uninitialized value $string in substitution (s///) at CreateEntity.pl line 68, <HANDLE>
Use of uninitialized value $string in substitution (s///) at CreateEntity.pl line 67, <HANDLE>
Use of uninitialized value $string in substitution (s///) at CreateEntity.pl line 68, <HANDLE>
```

And here is the code itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# This fils SHOULD go in the root of Symfony... put it anywhere else AT YOUR OWN RISK !!!

use warnings;

# Declare the subroutines
sub trim;

if(!defined $ARGV[0])
{
    die( "No FilePath Specified!\n" );

}

my $entityFile = $ARGV[0];

open( HANDLE, $entityFile ) or die( "The file could not be open!" );

my $entityCmd = "php app/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity=\"rapliqBundle:";
my $entityName = "";

chomp( my $line = ( <HANDLE> ) );
$line = trim( $line );
while( $line ne "END" )
{
    if( trim( $line ) ~~ "NAME:" )
    {
        chomp( $line = ( <HANDLE> ) );
        $entityName = trim( $line );
        $entityCmd = $entityCmd . $entityName;
        $entityCmd = $entityCmd . "\" --fields=\"";
    }
    elsif( trim( $line) ~~ "FIELDS:" )
    {
        chomp( $line = ( <HANDLE> ) );
        my @data = split( '=', $line );
        foreach my $val (@data) 
        {
            $val = trim( $val );
            if( $val ~~ lc "string" )
            {
                $entityCmd = $entityCmd . $val . "(255) ";
            }
            else
            {
                $entityCmd = $entityCmd . $val . ":";
            }
        }
    }

    52: chomp( $line = ( <HANDLE> ) );
}

close( HANDLE );
$entityCmd = $entityCmd . "\"";

#print $entityCmd;

system( $entityCmd );
system( "php app/console doctrine:generate:entities rapliqBundle:" . $entityName );
system( "php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force");

sub trim
{
    my $string = $_[0];
    67:$string =~ s/^\s+//;
    68:$string =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $string;
}
```

Thanks for any idea or comments :)

EDIT: I put the line number for the concerned line in front of the line of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all comes down to handling the end of your input file better.

1. Use of uninitialized value $line in chomp at CreateEntity.pl line 52,  line 5.

   `<HANDLE>` returns undef to indicate you've reached the end of the file. You ignore this and attempt to chomp the returned value.
2. Use of uninitialized value $line in string ne at CreateEntity.pl line 52,  line 5.

   Misreported line number. The warning is actually coming from `$line ne "END"`.

   `$line` is still undefined from having reached the end of the file.
3. Use of uninitialized value $string in substitution (s///) at CreateEntity.pl line 67,
4. Use of uninitialized value $string in substitution (s///) at CreateEntity.pl line 68,

   `trim( $line ) ~~ "NAME:"`

   `$line` is still undefined from having reached the end of the file.
5. Use of uninitialized value $string in substitution (s///) at CreateEntity.pl line 67,
6. Use of uninitialized value $string in substitution (s///) at CreateEntity.pl line 68,

   `trim( $line) ~~ "FIELDS:"`

   `$line` is still undefined from having reached the end of the file.

You should trim a line only once, and there's no need to chomp if you're going to trim.

---

In a flash of brilliance, I think I know what you're underlying problem is :)

Your data file has Windows line endings. You chomp the line, leaving you with `"END\r"` instead of `"END"`. The `dos2unix` command line tool would fix that, and so would `trim`ming.

```
while (my $line = <HANDLE>) {
   $line = trim( $line );
   last if $line eq "END";
   ...
}
```